# Widget selections do not show up "sometimes"

Tags: android, widget

I'm the developer for the Banner app in the Play Store. Every great once in a while I get an email from a user that says, "*I've installed your app, but its not showing up in widgets*". I cant reproduce it on any device or emulator, but I did witness it once on a friends old Droid (original). However, an uninstall/reinstall fixed it and I couldn't get it to do it again (it is an old/slow device).

I've had my app in the market for close to 2 years and I rarely get this feedback and my score is 4.4 stars so it cant be super common.

Anyone else know of this? ***Is it Android itself*** or maybe something I can do extra in my code.

```
<receiver
            android:name="kenyu73.bannerwidget.BannerWidget"
            android:label="Banner 4x1 (large)" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_1x4" />
        </receiver>
```

..

```
public class BannerWidget1x4 extends AppWidgetProvider {

    // contains ALL ids on boot, but only the current id when a new banner is created...
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Logger.d("BANNER", "BannerWidget1x4:onUpdate");

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Logger.d("BANNER", "BannerWidget1x4:onUpdate -> widgetid " + appWidgetIds[i] + " updated!");
            BannerWidgetBase.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
        }
    }

    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Logger.d("BANNER", "BannerWidget1x4:onEnabled");

    }

    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Logger.d("BANNER", "BannerWidget1x4:onDeleted -> widgetid " + appWidgetIds[0] + " deleted!");

        BannerWidgetBase.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No tips, thoughts or the like yet.. (=

Comment: This may be related: 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24208